# PHP and Javascript - On select change fill in 2 further selects

Tags: javascript

I have a SQL datatable with 4 fields of info for a list of "Hazards":

ID
HazardName
DefaultInjury
DefaultSeverity

I have a form with 3 dropdowns (selections).  The 1st 1 is filled in via AJAX with the ID and HazardName.  The other 2 selections are filled with values and labels from other data tables.

What I want to do.. is when I select a hazard (on change) I want to set the 2nd selction with the DefaultInjury value and the 3rd selection with the DefaultSeverity value.

Is there an easy way to do this, such as having hidden extra values in the selections?

What I'm trying to avoid is having to use AJAX again to retrieve the values from the database again.

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: There are several ways to do this, I particularly when working with high volume of options I load all results and show / hide only what I need, others prefer to load only what is relevant. Post your code.

Comment: It's not a great volume only about 50 records in this case.   I've decided to load the information into a 2D array and use the onchange attribute (hopefully)